How to specify a nested class for x:DataType in a DataTemplate?
When I try to use x:DataType in a DataTemplate to specify the nested class, I get an error.
I have a nested class structure in C#, as shown below:
namespace sample
{
    public class MainData
    {
        public class SubData
        {
        }
    }
}

XAML
xmlns:local="using:sample"

<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MainData.SubData">
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

This results in a compile-time error because MainData.SubData is not recognized as a valid type.
Is there a way to specify a nested class like MainData.SubData for x:DataType in XAML?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Try the following syntax with + instead of ..
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MainData+SubData">
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

At the moment?, Visual Studio will throw some errors but the app should run. Check this issue on GitHub.

I tried that method, but it still resulted in an error.
It seems to be a bug, so I've decided to use a method that doesn't involve nested classes for now. Thank you.
Error
The type 'local:MainData+SubData' could not be found. Ensure that the assembly reference has not been lost and that all referenced assemblies are built.
'MainData' is a type. This is invalid in the specified content.
The name 'SubData' does not exist in the current context.

Like I mentioned in my answer, Visual Studio will throw errors but the app should run. I just confirmed it with a sample app for this answer.

I wonder why? We don't know yet, but we will add a note when we find the cause.
